# Display images in Mosaic "without holes"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I try to put pictures in a photo album or a div row so it would be "optimized" the vignatures images,

In fact I try to recreate the management of sites Google Images +,

Is there any resource for that?

The algorithm seems to me to be a real headlock to arrive at this result as:

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=15859466a1.png

Any idea to begin with ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for that: [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).